# symfony2:You have requested a non-existent parameter "secret"

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

After installing and configured sonata admin. I have got following error in my framework. Please help..

You have requested a non-existent parameter "secret".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Be sure to import your parameters.yml file at the top of you config.yml file

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
```

Comment: Oh thanks - Actually this is already imported but I have created new class that extends sonata admin which need to be import...Resolved     this is new admin.yml which extends sonataAdmin

    imports:
        - { resource: @websitecontactBundle/Resources/config/admin.yml }

Comment: I ran into a similar issue when I upgraded to Symfony 2.8 from 2.6. Installing my configs from the old symfony, it's easy to miss something. It just means that whatever parameter yaml is expecting, in this case "secret" wasn't found. Create it or stop using it.

Answer (score 2):

In your parameters.yml, you must have an attribute "secret", because in your config.yml you have a reference to "secret" with this line : secret: %secret%

Comment: Thanks for reply.. In parameters.yml already defined. Even I commented secret: %secret% in config.yml then same error come for "locale" which also defined in parameters.yml

Comment: Even my parameters.yml looks like this:                                                              # This file is auto-generated during the composer install
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: 192.168.100.96
    database_port: null
    database_name: utkarsh_parekh
    database_user: utkarsh_parekh
    database_password: deep70
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    locale: en
    secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt

Answer (score 2):

This error can occur if you add a second `imports` section to your `config.yml`, overriding the first default directive that imports `parameters.yml`.

Answer (score 2):

**2 steps** To resolve this bug :

1.Be sure to import your parameters.yml file at the top of you config.yml file

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
```

2.Be sure to add your missing variable in parameters.yml

```
secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
```